# How to use random.random() to generates pseudo-random real numbers between 30 and 35?

Tags: python, random

I know that random.random() generates pseudo-random real numbers between 0 and 1. But what
if I needed other random reals? for example between 30 and 35. I am trying to write this function but I am stuck in the middle Please help me.

Thank you All.

```
import random
def generate_random():
""" Make a list of 10 random reals between 30 and 35 """
random.seed()
pass
```

Comment: Or even better, multiply by 4 and add 30

Comment: multiply what by 30 and 4 can you specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random
def generate_random():
    return [random.randint(30, 35) for _ in range(10)]
```

Or this:

```
import random
def generate_random():
    return [30+5*random.random() for _ in range(10)]
```

Comment: I have to use only random.random()

Comment: Well, random.random() can take no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
from random import random
x = [random()*5+30 for p in range(0, 10)]
print(x)
```

output:

```
[33.42156572091028, 34.34567526662949, 32.032391323008056, 33.25221139836125, 31.149272884440236, 33.9733171427812, 34.684482360876856, 34.927541219373296, 30.99028290511958, 34.344225720130446]
```

Comment: I think they wanted real numbers

Comment: I think you are right but the condition is that I have to use only random.random()

Comment: Sorry for the mistake @S.Strempfer. And you can also use uniform(). But with random this is one of the possible ways

Comment: oh man there is no need to say sorry Thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def problem2_4():
    random.seed() # if u need concrete numbers
    x = [] # list for generated numbers
    for num in range():
        x.append(30+5*random.random())
    print(x)
```